# Changing first number(0) in SteamID to 1 using PHP/MySQL (STEAM_0->STEAM_1)?

Tags: php, mysql

How to change from 0 to 1 from an input PHP that's being tranferred to MySQL?

```
STEAM_0:1:100554204
```

To

```
STEAM_1:1:100554204
```

Here is where they input it:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <label>SteamID</label>
   <input type="text" name="steamid" value="<?php echo $steamid; ?>">
   <p />
</div>
```

Here's my MySQL Query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, steamid, password, points, vip, admin, headadmin, owner) 
        VALUES('$username', '$steamid', '$password', '$points', '$vip', '$admin', '$headadmin', '$owner')";
```

EDIT:
Here is what I've come up with, but how do I make it detect it starts as STEAM_0...?

```
if ($steamid == '(STEAM_0)...') {
    $newsteamid = preg_replace('/(STEAM_)(0){1}/i', '${1}1', $steamid);
}
```

Comment: Is `STEAM_0:1:100554204` the output of a query which you are trying to transform, or are you asking something else?

Comment: When people enter a SteamID on a input-field it's getting tranferred to MySQL. I want it so before transferring, it should autochange to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.

Use `str_replace` to replace occurrence of 'STEAM_0' with 'STEAM_1'.

```
echo str_replace('STEAM_0', 'STEAM_1', 'STEAM_0:1:100554204');
```

Use `preg_replace` to replace the first 0 after 'STEAM_'.

```
echo preg_replace('/(STEAM_)(0){1}/i', '${1}1', 'STEAM_0:1:100554204');
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but how should I do it, when people insert a SteamID that consists of STEAM_0 and enters it to my MySQL? I would like it to store it as STEAM_1

Comment: Set `$steamid` to the updated value before the insert query. Also consider using parameterized query. As it is with your current query, your db is susceptible to injection attacks

Comment: Look my latest Edit of what I've come up with so far, but how do I make it detect if STEAM_0...?

Comment: No need for the _precondition_.  `$streamid = str_replace('STEAM_0', 'STEAM_1', 'STEAM_0:1:100554204');` will suffice

Comment: Amazing, problem solved - I've just replaced the actual SteamID value with the $steamid that players input :)